# How can I run my Node.js webserver on two free dynos?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am experimenting with Heroku's free version. I have two free dynos.

I have a simple web server and I want to run this web server on two dynos.

How can I do this?

I didn't found any help in Heroku doc (only cluster recommendation).

Code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()  

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(`Hello World`) 
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

`Procfile`:

```
web: node web.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't use Heroku's regular scaling functionality with free dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling):

> Heroku apps can be scaled to run on multiple dynos simultaneously (except on Free or Hobby dynos). You can scale your app’s dyno formation up and down manually from the Heroku Dashboard or CLI.

You should be able to provision a new app (e.g. via `heroku create`) and manually deploy your code there as well (e.g. via `git push second-app master`), but of course you won't get any kind of load balancing. Instead of one logical app running on two dynos you'll have two logical apps each running on one dyno.

Theoretically you could set up your own load balancer outside of the Heroku ecosystem, but if you're going to do that you might as well just pay for professional-tier dynos.